# Is one forbidden or permitted to use a pogo-stick on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat

I have found that using a spring in itself is permitted on Shabbat (e.g. https://www.sefaria.org/Peninei_Halakhah%2C_Shabbat.15.8.7?vhe=Peninei_Halakhah,_Yeshivat_Har_Bracha&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

What then is the status of using a [pogo-stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_stick) on Shabbat?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! It would be helpful if you explained what a pogo-stick is to the many who will not know. This will help you get better answers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bicycle on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/bicycle-on-shabbat)

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think halachichally it's the same din as for a bicycle. Very cool first question, though, I hope you stick around and learn with us!

Comment: @יהושעק it's not necessarily the same, there might be the problem of jumping, for example