Can you ride a bike on Yom Tov?
Are you allowed to ride a bike on Yom Tov (e.g. the first two and last two days of Pesach in the US)?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/bicycle-on-shabbat  based on most reasons given on that question, it would apply to YT as well.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6711/if-no-one-else-was-available-could-a-mohel-ride-a-bicycle-on-shabbos-to-perform#comment69184_6711
